# Issue with Jquery Datatable fnAdjustColumnSizing

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am getting **"TypeError: settings is undefined"** issue while calling fnAdjustColumnSizing function.

Currently I am using DataTables 1.10.15 version

```
$('#myDataTable').dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
```

or

```
var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable();
oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
```

Giving the same error

[image]

[image]

console log value for api.settings()

```
  ({context:[], length:0, selector:{rows:null, cols:null, opts:null}, tables:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), table:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), draw:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), page:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), ajax:{__dt_wrapper:true, json:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), params:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), reload:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), url:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    })}, rows:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), row:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), columns:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), column:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), cells:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), cell:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), order:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), search:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), state:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), $:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), on:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), one:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), off:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), clear:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), settings:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), init:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), data:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), destroy:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    }), i18n:(function () {

                        var ret = fn.apply(scope, arguments);

                        // Method extension
                        _Api.extend(ret, ret, struc.methodExt);
                        return ret;

                    })})
```

Comment: You did not get your desired value in `var api = this.api(true).columns.adjust();`. You should start there.

Comment: Confirm if your **this** in `this.api(true).columns.adjust();` is really pointing to your datatable. You can try console.log(this); to verify the value of your this.

Comment: I got this value
({selector:"#myDataTable", context:{get location() {
    [native code]
}, set location() {
    [native code]
}, _html5shiv:1, jQuery191040327884304888306:1}, length:0})

Comment: maybe it's not yet a datatable that's why you get that result. Try changing it to $(this).Datatable().api(true).columns.adjust()

Comment: still no luck; got this error TypeError: $(...).datatable is not a function

Comment: Sorry, it should be DataTable(). Javascript is case-sensitive i think.
And you can remove the .api(true) also since columns.adjust returns the api already.

Comment: Did you mistype the small t in table?

Comment: Yes, I correct my typo, but now back to original error
TypeError: settings is undefined

Comment: What is the result of this, `console.log(api.settings());`

Comment: Its too long; I have append log value in main question

Comment: W8, are you sure that api.settings return an array? Based on the API, it returns an object.

Comment: Try removing `[0]` in `.settings()` since it is not an array. Check if you got something using `console.log(settings);`

Comment: Yes I think its working, can put it as answer so I can tick as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `api.settings()` returns an object instead of an array. Need to remove `[0]` to get the settings object.